# UtmStack: Where are install logs? Not found in /var/log

Tags: utm

The Installation Guide indicates the installation logs are available at /var/log/utm-setup.log. However there is nothing at this location, nor is there a utm-setup or *setup.log anywhere to be found. There does not appear to be anything in /var/log for UTM. Where are the logs? This is for the Ubuntu installation in a vanilla 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTMStack creates those logs only if you are installing using the TUI mode.

[UTMStack Installer Code Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhe92.png)

The exact route of the installation logs is "/var/log/utm-setup.log"

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text that you could copy&paste. Just copy the text and use the [formatting tools](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) to make it readable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have time to copy and paste and then format and indent the code.

Comment: Well, good look with that attitude.

Comment: What about bothering anyone that wants to help?